# How to count the number of occurences in a column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I'm trying to count the number of occurences in a single column. Here is a snippet of the df I'm working with:
[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
my_df$day <- weekdays(as.Date(my_df$deadline))
most_common_day <- my_df %>%
arrange(day) %>%
filter(day == "Friday") %>%
select(day)
```

So the main goal is to get which weekday is the most common. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to count the number of occurrences in R. The basic R method is `table()`:

```r
table(my_df$day)
#   Friday    Monday  Saturday    Sunday  Thursday   Tuesday Wednesday 
#        4         6         8        11         6         5        10
```

The dplyr approach can be with `count()`:

```r
count(my_df, day)
#        day  n
#1    Friday  4
#2    Monday  6
#3  Saturday  8
#4    Sunday 11
#5  Thursday  6
#6   Tuesday  5
#7 Wednesday 10
```

You can also use `tally()` from dplyr but you will also need `group_by()`:

```r
my_df %>% group_by(day) %>% tally
#        day  n
#1    Friday  4
#2    Monday  6
#3  Saturday  8
#4    Sunday 11
#5  Thursday  6
#6   Tuesday  5
#7 Wednesday 10
```

**To get the *most* common day(s), you can do:**

```r
# when using table()
names(table(my_df$day))[table(my_df$day) == max(table(my_df$day))]
#[1] "Sunday"

# when using count()
count(my_df, day) %>% slice_max(n)
#     day  n
#1 Sunday 11


# when using tally()
my_df %>% group_by(day) %>% tally %>% slice_max(n)
## A tibble: 1 x 2
#  day        n
#  <fct>  <int>
#1 Sunday    11
```

Comment: Thank you! Using Tally since I want to familiarize myself with Dplyr